# Woocommerce local pickup plus php pickup date and time

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time, woocommerce

Is there a way to get the pickup date en time with php? I tried it with the following

```
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
  $pickup_date        = $item->get_meta('_pickup_date');
  $pickup_min_hours   = $item->get_meta('_pickup_minimum_hours');
}

foreach( $order->get_shipping_methods() as $item_id => $item ){
  $pickup_date        = $item->get_meta('_pickup_date');
  $pickup_min_hours   = $item->get_meta('_pickup_minimum_hours');
}
```

But with both I only get is two empty strings.

```
string(0) "" string(0) ""
```

I also tried it with

```
$pickup_date = get_post_meta( $order, '_pickup_date', true );
```

But that one also shows an empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe for some one else, but here is the answer.

you need te following foreach loop

```
foreach( $order->get_items('shipping') as $item_id => $shipping_item_obj )
```

And in that loop you can access the following meta:

```
_pickup_appointment_end
_pickup_appointment_start
_pickup_items
_pickup_location_address
_pickup_location_id
_pickup_location_name
_pickup_location_phone
```

Please note that the appointment start and end values are set to server timestamps

for my part I needed the following:

```
foreach( $order->get_items('shipping') as $item_id => $shipping_item_obj ) {
    $pickup_appointment_end   = $shipping_item_obj->get_meta('_pickup_appointment_end');
    $endtime = date('H:i', $pickup_appointment_end);
    $enddate = date('d-m-Y', $pickup_appointment_end);
    $pickup_appointment_start = $shipping_item_obj->get_meta('_pickup_appointment_start');
    $starttime = date('H:i', $pickup_appointment_start);
    $startdate = date('d-m-Y', $pickup_appointment_start);
  }
```